# How i can calculate from textbox value (int) to label (int)

Tags: c#

hey guys i stuck on my application project because this validation, anyone can help me solve this problem. I have some `Textbox` value as `int` and i want to calculate like multiplication or something else into a `Label` text .

```
public void LoadDataById()
{
    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = konn.GetConn();
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "select * from Ms_Register WHERE ID='" + Form_Pembayaran.dataRegistrasi.Id + "'";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            textBox2.Text = reader["nama"].ToString();
            richTextBox1.Text = reader["alamat"].ToString();
            textBox4.Text = reader["atasnama"].ToString();
            textBox5.Text = reader["keperluanpemb"].ToString();
            textBox6.Text = reader["jalan"].ToString();
            textBox7.Text = reader["kelurahandesa"].ToString();
            textBox8.Text = reader["kecamatan"].ToString();
            textBox9.Text = reader["luastanah"].ToString();
            textBox10.Text = reader["status"].ToString();
            textBox11.Text = reader["penggunaantanah"].ToString();

            textBox2.Enabled = false;
            richTextBox1.Enabled = false;
            textBox4.Enabled = false;
            textBox5.Enabled = false;
            textBox6.Enabled = false;
            textBox7.Enabled = false;
            textBox8.Enabled = false;
            textBox9.Enabled = false;
            textBox10.Enabled = false;
            textBox11.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

The code is showing a value into a textbox by id and the problem is how can i calculate the result of 1 value from textbox like example "Total Price" into a label so i want make a validation like this ( Total price *3) Into a label.
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Please show what you already tried.

Comment: And your problem is...? You can use .Text in TextBox and Label

Comment: would you please update your question with an example textbox value and the result you are trying to achieve, along with what you have already tried.  your question is unclear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, this is how you convert a textbox value to integer and then save back as text:

```
var myInt = Convert.ToInt32(tbMyTextBox.Text);
var myResult = myInt * 3;
lblMyLabel.Text = myResult.ToString();
```

This assumes that you expect tbMyTextBox value to be an integer.

Comment: Be careful about that conversion though... Don't want your program to blow up if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Here is other way to do this with checking whether `inputTextBox` has text which can be converted to `int`.

```
int intValue;
if (Int32.TryParse(inputTextBox.Text, out intValue))
{
    totalLabel.Text = (intValue * 3).ToString();
}
```